# Purpose of about="#this" -

Tags: rdf, rdfa

In learning about RDFa *(with excellent help from others here, I might add)* I have sometimes seen the subject specified using about="#this" rather than about="*someOtherURI*" or even the special about="#me" *(which I will likely ask about later)*. Now, I just had it explained to me that about="#anythingElse" creates a relative URI that refers to the entity 'anythingElse,' giving a full URI equivalent to the current base URI with the "#anythingElse" fragment appended onto the end.

This question is different. ... I hope. Does using about="#this" cause the RDF subject to become the entire XML or XHTML element which contains that attribute, including any content and child-elements? Even regardless of where that XML element may be found or copied to? In other words, here is a description of what I would like to see happen:

1) A blank node is created in the RDF graph.

2) This blank node contains or represents all of the content between the start tag, containing the about="#this" attribute, and its end tag. That content could be a couple of lines of text, an entire section of a web page (with child elements, etcetera), or an entire document.

3) All the predicates and objects "tripled" *(Is that a verb?)* with this subject are connected to that blank node in the graph.

4) That blank node could even be assigned a URI (via a separate predicate and object) that may not be the current base URI of the document.

Please note that this is not the same as setting the base URI using the `<BASE>` HTML element. That merely changes the default base URI from one matching the URL of the actual document to some other URI for purposes of completing relative URIs.

What I am talking about creates a subject node with no URI, but which could be assigned one later.

Nor am I talking about manually setting the subject as a blank node using about="_:someIDcode" . That does not indicate that the entire contents of the containing XML element are the contents of said blank node. All it does is create an entirely blank **and empty** node as a place holder.

Is my hope true? Or is this just rampant wishful thinking?

The reason I am hoping it is true is because it seems pretty limiting for an RDF subject to only be able to refer to an entire and separate web document, rather than to parts of a web document. Now, I understand that the subject URI can refer to any entity, real or abstract. But, within the narrow context of the subject referring to a document, I would like it to be able to refer to a part of a document, and without that part of a document necessarily needing to be located at any hard URL.

If my wish is not true, then is my only option to label my XML element with an @ID attribute and then set the subject to the URI which matches the URL of the document plus the fragment pointing to this element? That, to me, still seems dissatisfying because the URI would then change any time the document URL changed, thus breaking any triples pointing to this content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDFa is primarily just a mechanism to embed RDF into HTML exploiting the structure of HTML for syntactic convenience and ease of expressing nested structures.  It is not a way of talking about the structure of the HTML itself.  The `about` sets the current subject for generating triples for that node and its child nodes but that is purely for the purposes of parsing and is not actually expressing structural information about the HTML in any way.

`#this` is simply an arbitrary fragment identifier typically used by convention to refer to the overall document, it has no special meaning in of itself.  Ultimately it just creates a URI which is an identifier for some arbitrary thing in the RDF world.

Similarily `#me` is again an arbitrary fragment identifier that by convention is typically used in [FOAF](http://www.foaf-project.org/) files to refer to the person the file is describing.  Again it is ultimately just a URI used to identify some thing (in this case usually a person) in RDF

So in answer to your question no it does not work how you hope it does

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess the next question is: If I were to specify the above specific meaning in my own vocabulary, would an RDF "reasoner" program be able to handle it without too much problem? I know my use is outside of the normal expectations that a fragment identifier, when used this way in RDFa, merely represents a relative URI. So, would reasoners have to be completely rewritten or just slightly modified to understand my vocabulary?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a work-around - of sorts - to this issue of wishing to have an XML or XHTML element exist on its own regardless of what document it may be placed in.

Use something to the effect of the following:

```
<div about="_:anyUniqueIDForThisDocument"
     property="http://www.myDomain.com/mySpecialCitationPredicate"
     content="aUniqueCitationIDThatIControlTheSequenceOf">
    <!-- Put any other stuff in here. Then write a processor that looks for any XML
         elements it can find that are similarly marked with the same unique citation
         ID and treats them as if they are the same "floating" element regardless of
         where they are found.
     -->
</div>
```

This gives the same result in a round-about way. Your RDF processor will know to match up all the XML elements it finds based on that unique citation ID.